# ObjectListView advanced search and filtering

Tags: c#, objectlistview, treelistview

I'm trying to search and filter results on a TreeListView object from the ObjectListView component. Currently, I'm implementing this into a C# (.NET 4.0) project which have the following classes

MyAbstract, MyDir (inherit MyAbstract) and MyFile (inherit MyAbstract as well). These classes have the following properties: Name, Title, Speed, SpeedType.

I want to know how to correctly create a query-like filter to this list, such as for example:

```
Speed < 10 OR SpeedType == "RPM"
```

I probably might use LINQ to it, but my main problem is how to apply and manage this using the TreeListView. My main questions are:

1. How to create this kind of filtering on the TreeListView?
2. How to make the TreeListView display only the filtered results
3. How to make it save the original list to have a clear filter button.

This is how I currently setup my list:

```
public void Init()
{
    Project.LoadDirectory();

    treeListView1.SetObjects(new object[] { Project.Root });

    treeListView1.CanExpandGetter = delegate(object x)
    {
        return (x is MyDir);
    };

    treeListView1.ChildrenGetter = delegate(object x)
    {
        return ((MyDir)x).Nodes;
    };

    olvColumn1.ImageGetter = new ImageGetterDelegate(this.TreeViewImageGetter);
}
```

I've looked over [the documentation](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/filtering.html) but it stills unclear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What have you tried?

This will filter the `TreeListView` to only show `MyFile` objects that match the condition you gave in your question:

```
this.treeListView.ModelFilter = new ModelFilter(delegate(object x) {
    var myFile = x as MyFile;
    return x != null && (myFile.Speed < 10 || myFile.SpeedType == "RPM");
});
```

To stop filtering, just clear the file again:

```
this.treeListView.ModelFilter = null;
```

The demo that comes with the project shows all this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think I should make my question clear as what I really want to know is how to make this kind of search. In your example, you know what I I'll search, but I want to make it more query-like allowing the user to make different type of search queries.

Comment: You asked three questions, and this answer addressed each one. Implementing a query language is really quite a separate issue.

Comment: Yeah, thank you again. I've searched it and I can see that my search question is not related directly with this.